# Can a Sony Vaio upgrade to Windows 8 from Windows 7?

Tags: windows-8, installation, sony-vaio

When I spoke with Sony support they said that my Sony Vaio VPCSA can't run Windows 8. I find that unlikely, can you confirm that it can't? What exactly is it that makes it not possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Driver support from the vendor is what determines this. If Sony doesn't make Windows 8 drivers, you have a few options:

Install it and use Windows 7 drivers. This will probably not be completely stable.

Install it and track down the OEM drivers for each component. For example, if you have a RealTek audio device, you'd have to track the download down on RealTek's site rather than Sony's. Lather, rinse, repeat for every device in your system (and hope that all of these drivers exist).

Don't install it and stick with Windows 7 and know that you'll be relatively stable.

Comment: +1, I want to add that most likely, it *will* run Win8.  You might not have drivers for things like webcam, smartcard readers, etc.

Comment: You could try a parallel install of Win8, thus keeping Win7